# Adding legend to lattice xyplot

Tags: r, legend, lattice

I am trying to add a legend to the right hand side of this xyplot using the simpleKey function but can't seem to get the syntax correct. I am trying to make a legend to differentiate between males and females on both of these plots.

This is my code for the plot:
[image]

and this is the resulting plot

[image]

so the brown ("peru") points are females and the blue ("cornflowerblue") are males.

I hope I have given enough detail - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`simpleKey()` will not be useful here. You could use `key = list(...)` directly, but then you would need to repeat your `col` and `pch` arguments. I would suggest replacing these with

```r
xyplot(...,
       par.settings = simpleTheme(pch = c(16, 17), 
               col = c("peru", "cornflowerblue")), 
       auto.key = list(space = "right"))
```